# Informatica Cloud (IICS) filename using wildcard

Tags: mapping, informatica, informatica-cloud, filepattern

In Data Integration module, I have created a mapping to load data from Csv file to Oracle table. I want to give a file pattern as the file name will have date in it. When I try to provide file pattern in the Source object, it is throwing the below error.

[image]

If someone can assist on letting me know how to load file with a file pattern, it will be very helpful.

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a File Listener as the source for this mapping. In File Listener settings you can provide the pattern - and in turn, File Listener will trigger the mapping with the file found.